# Adding items to QlistView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qlistwidget, qlistview

I'm using pyqt4 with python 2.7 and I have a list view widget that I can't add items to it

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'add_category.ui'
#
# Created: Mon Mar 19 23:22:30 2018
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.10
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog1(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(608, 460)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/media/media/in.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Dialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 6, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Adobe Arabic"))
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.listView = QtGui.QListView(Dialog)
        self.listView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listView"))
        entries = ['one','two', 'three']

        for i in entries:
            item = QtGui.QListView(i)
            self.listView.addItem(item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listView, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/media/media/ok.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_2.setIcon(icon1)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        def go_back(self):
            Dialog.hide()
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(go_back)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "إضافة فئة", None))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Dialog", "هنا يكتب الاسم الفئة الجديدة", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "إضافة", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "إسـم الفئة الجديدة", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "موافق", None))

import resrcs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog1()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As you guys can see i used

```
entries = ['one','two', 'three']

for i in entries:
    item = QtGui.QListView(i)
    self.listView.addItem(item)
```

But it gave me an error that is talking about arguments and data types:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\townoftechwarehouse\add_category.py", line 84, in <module>
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
  File "C:\python\townoftechwarehouse\add_category.py", line 54, in setupUi
    item = QtGui.QListView(i)
TypeError: QListView(QWidget parent=None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
[Finished in 1.7s]
```

Also, is it right to use ListView here or I should use listwidget?

In general, what is the difference between both !!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`QListWidget` is a class of higher level that makes the developer can handle it easily, for example `QListWidget` has a model of type `QStantandardItemModel` that can not be accessed, in addition to built the `QListWidgetItem` to handle the data, as you have seen is simple add data through functions like `addItem()` or `addItems()`.

On the other hand `QListView`, from which `QListWidget` inherits, is of lower level, where you can customize many things, using custom models, etc.

You can use both:

#### QListView

```
self.listView = QtGui.QListView(Dialog)
self.listView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listView"))

entries = ['one', 'two', 'three']

model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
self.listView.setModel(model)

for i in entries:
    item = QtGui.QStandardItem(i)
    model.appendRow(item)

self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listView, 1, 0, 1, 2)
```

#### QListWidget

```
self.listwidget = QtGui.QListWidget(Dialog)

entries = ['one', 'two', 'three']

self.listwidget.addItems(entries)

self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listwidget, 1, 0, 1, 2)
```